# mysql get state on particular date

Tags: mysql

How could I get row from table with dates nearest to some date? If if insert log on February 27th, state will remain the same for some time and no other record will be added. How can I tell which state was on March 8th for instance?
I have two tables: State and History

```
State:           History:

id|name       id|    date   |id_state
1 |works      1 |2010-08-06 |1
2 |broken     2 |2011-05-10 |1
3 |active     3 |2009-27-01 |2
```

If I draw timeline of records when when were put in database...

```
2009-08-06                                  2010-08-06
---|--------------------------------------------|---------------->
'active'                                     'broken'
```

So it was active this entire time. I need all rows from History when state was active and date was March 8th 2010. Thank you

Comment: can you please post at least a sketchy version of your "log table" DDL , some sample data, and expected result? that would help answer your question without guessing too much

Comment: Have you no about joins?

Answer (score 0):

To get the last state before a given date (which will give you the state at the given date), use this query:

```
select * from (
    select *
    from log_table
    where `date` < $1
    and name = 'active'
    order by `date` desc) x
limit 1
```

You can add to the where clause as you like to find the most recent row *with some particular condition*.

Comment: I'm not looking for the last one but the one that was active on particular date

Comment: then just add `and name = 'active'` to the inner where clause. try it - it should work

Comment: also, did you realise that this query gives you exactly what you want? IT gives you the last record before the given date, which is the active one on that date

Answer (score 0):

Simple query. Considering your mentioned date of 8th March 2010.

```
select h.id, h.date,h.id_state from history h
left outer join State s on s.id = h.id_state
where 
h.date = '2010-03-08' and s.id = 3
```

You can rephrase the where clause as below according to your need.

```
where h.date = '2010-03-08' and s.name = 'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
SELECT state.id, history.id, name, date 
FROM state
JOIN history ON state.id = history.id_state 
WHERE date = '2010-08-06'
```

Simple joining of 2 tables...

**Edit:**
To retrieve the last closest date to the given date, use this...

```
SELECT state.id, history.id, name, date
FROM state
JOIN history ON state.id = history.id_state
WHERE date <= '2012-04-10'
ORDER by date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You get exactly ONE, but the closest date...

**Edit2:**
To retrieve the last closest date to the given date, that IS ACTIVE...

```
SELECT state.id, history.id, name, date
FROM state
JOIN history ON state.id = history.id_state
WHERE date <= '2012-04-10' AND name = 'active'
ORDER by date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You get exactly ONE, but the closest date...

Comment: Problem is that March 8th is not stored in table but March 6th is for instance because on that day state has changed to 'active' and it remained active even after that date.

Comment: So you need to retrieve the closest date to given date?

Comment: Yes. Closest smaler that is active

Comment: 1st edit gives you row with last known state and date. 2nd one gives you row with last know active state.

Comment: Limit 1 is the problem here :) Unfortanetely I need all rows that match conditions